# Snapshot a directory

Tags: 18.04, snapshot, 20.04

I have an Ubuntu 18.04 (upgrading to 20.04 when released) laptop with a nice MicroSD slot. I'd like to setup a process to have snapshots of a particular home directory, let's say `~/code`, to be done hourly and stored on the MicroSD card. However, the snapshots should also be consolidated at the end of the day, and then end of the week and only done if there were changes.

Is there an easy way to do this without lots of manual scripting? And especially if there is already application capable of doing that?

Comment: I'd use `rsync` and `cron` for this task

Comment: What have you tried so far? If there was an error message, please click [edit] and provide both the commend(s) you ran and the results. Please do not use Add Comment.

Comment: All I've tried so far is searching for an existing tool with no good results.